# Flutter :How to print shared preferences all content

Tags: flutter, set, sharedpreferences

I want to print all sharedpreferences content (key,value) 
Keys and Values are given by the user

I've tried to put all Keys into a Set using getKeys() Method then loop the Set and retrieve my elements like this:

```
 _favoritePlaces() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // prefKeys declared as  static Set<String>
    prefKeys=prefs.getKeys();
    if (prefKeys.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < prefKeys.length; i++) {
       // this is another function expects to find key given as parameter
        _drawerItem(prefKeys.elementAt(i).toString());
      // expected output should come below
       
      }
    }
  }
```

Expected Output :
Key0 => Value0

Comment: are you getting an error message? what's going wrong?

Comment: whenever I add print(prefKeys.elementAt(0)) Exception :No Directionality widget found

Comment: so you only have an issue if you add a line to the for loop of 'print(prefKeys.elementAt(0));'?

Comment: my issue is to print all keys and values from sharedprefrences directly but here i've used set(collection) to manipulate the problem but I don't know if this is an efficient way to do it if  I can't retieve data directly from prefs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm worried there is no such API exposed (publicly) to get all prefs at once by the shared_preferences plugin.

You need to do that yourself. This worked for me:

```dart
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<List<Widget>> getAllPrefs() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await PrefStore().prefs;
    return prefs
        .getKeys()
        .map<Widget>((key) => ListTile(
              title: Text(key),
              subtitle: Text(prefs.get(key).toString()),
            ))
        .toList(growable: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Widget>>(
          future: getAllPrefs(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data,
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed a `Map` of the shared preferences key value pairs, sharing if anyone needs it.

```
Future<Map<String, String>> getAllPrefs() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return <String, String>{
    for (String key in prefs.getKeys()) ...{key: prefs.get(key).toString()}
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I digged the code for shared_preferences and found out that they it is possible to do get all prefs at once by directly invoking method on the methodChannel (which i don't recommend, hence have kept the old answer also).

Here is how you can do that

```dart
    const MethodChannel _kChannel =
        MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences');
    final Map<Object, Object> fromSystem =
        await _kChannel.invokeMethod('getAll');
    print(fromSystem);
```

`fromSystem` is the `Map` that has all the values.

Note: One thing to notice is all keys have a prefix of "flutter.", for eg "user_id" will become "flutter.user_id".

Comment: Would you care to explain why you **don't** recommend? This is working very well for me.

Comment: Since MethodChannel communication is internal to plugin, they might do breaking changes some times without changing public methods. Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

**The same code as the correct answer above but with flutter 2 "null safety":**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<List<Widget>> getAllPrefs() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs
        .getKeys()
        .map<Widget>((key) => ListTile(
              title: Text(key),
              subtitle: Text(prefs.get(key).toString()),
            ))
        .toList(growable: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Widget>>(
          future: getAllPrefs(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!,
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```